# How to increase the max memory limit for the app built by electron-builder?

Tags: electron-builder

- **Version**:     "electron": "1.6.2", "electron-builder": "^16.8.2",
- **Target**: windows x64

I know I can add `--js-flags="--max-old-space-size=4096"` when run it using electron. But Where should I put this param to the build config of electron-builder?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In main.js, add:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('js-flags', '--max-old-space-size=4096');
```

According to [Supported Chrome Command Line Switches](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/command-line-switches.md), this should be called before the `ready` event is emitted. For example:

```
import { app } from "electron";

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('js-flags', '--max-old-space-size=4096');

app.on('ready', () => {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: What is 4096? Bytes, kilobytes, megabytes?

Comment: is megabytes @Finesse

Comment: I'm uploading large files with axios, but this is not solving the issue, do you have an idea ? thx

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add that, in my case, the `max-old-space-size` flag was only being successfully applied when I placed it in my webview's "preload" script, like so (Start_WebviewPreload.ts):

```
import {remote} from "electron";
remote.app.commandLine.appendSwitch("js-flags", "--max-old-space-size=8192");
```

Placing it in the "main.js" file (the entry point of the whole program), did not do anything. (I even checked the command-line arguments using Process Hacker 2 and it didn't show any of the electron processes as having that flag until I moved the code as mentioned above)

Also, I notice that there may be some kind of race condition between the setting of the command-line flag and the execution of `app.on("ready")` -- some of the time, the code above works for the main renderer process (the one not-in-the-webview), whereas other times it doesn't.

So basically: If you want to ensure your command-line switches work, apply them within the preload script for the given browser-window/web-view.